# How use select 2 dopdown list in angular 7

Tags: angular

I am using bootstrap with Angular 6.I have many drop down menus in my page and want to implement the functionality as there should be a textbox which on focus shows data in array and on typing shows autocomplete functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material has implemented Autocomplete functionality.
1 - import material library to app-module.ts

```
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
```

2 - use below code in your html

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

here 'options' is the array containing the autocomplete list.

```
options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
```

StackBlitz link - https://stackblitz.com/angular/yvynpjydopq?file=app%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.ts